# With parent display box, firefox doesn't resoect padding as percentage in child node

Tags: html, css, firefox

When the parent element has `display: box; display: -moz-box;` and the child has its padding set to a percentage, Firefox ignores the padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5udum49/

```
.parent
{
    width: 400px;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;   
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
}

.child
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5%;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
}
```

The above CSS code results in child's text being left aligned up against the border with 0 padding.

Chrome still shows the padding.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: This property is nonstandard, outdated and isn't a part of any current spec, why are you using it?

Comment: Yup, [good rundown of what old flexbox is here](https://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/) and [a good guide on the new display flex here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Nit Not very many browsers support the new flexbox, only this original style.

Comment: @DonRhummy - As this is not a standard you will see support for this outdated draft spec  dropped.

Comment: @DonRhummy change padding to a fixed value, i.e. padding: 20px;